# Как сгенерировать html код для вложенных списков

Tags: c#, openxml

В общем ситуация следующая я пытаюсь распарcить docx файл и представить его в виде html у меня возникли проблемы со вложенными списками. В процессе обработки параграфов я должен понять является ли параграф списком если он таким является, то я открываю тег `<ul>`

Это класс не из OpenXML, это объявленный мною класс

```
public class Paragraph
{
    public MainDocumentPart DocumentPart { get; set; }

    public OpenXmlElement Element { get; set; }

    public bool IsList { get; set; }

    public List? List { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public ListType ListType { get; set;}
}
```

У списка имеется уровень и тип(маркированный или нумерованный)

Обработчик параграфов

```
    public void ParagraphHandle(Elements.Paragraph paragraph, StringBuilder text)
    {
        var docPart = paragraph.DocumentPart;
        var element = paragraph.Element;

        var images = GetImages(docPart, element);

        if (images.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if (image.Id != null)
                {
                    string filePath = _saveResources.SaveImage(image);
                    _htmlGenerator.GenerateImage(filePath, text);
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        var paragraphProperties = element.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.ParagraphProperties>();

        var numberingProperties = paragraphProperties?.GetFirstChild<NumberingProperties>();

        if (numberingProperties != null)
        {
            var numberingId = numberingProperties.GetFirstChild<NumberingId>()?.Val?.Value;

            if (numberingId != null && !paragraph.IsList) // новый список
            {
                var instance = paragraph.DocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart?.Numbering
                    .Descendants<NumberingInstance>()
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.NumberID?.Value == numberingId);
                
                string? attributeValue = instance?.Descendants<AbstractNumId>().FirstOrDefault()
                    ?.GetAttribute("val", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main").Value;

                var level = paragraph.DocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart?.Numbering.Descendants<Level>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => ((AbstractNum)x.Parent!).AbstractNumberId == attributeValue);

                paragraph.List = new List();
                paragraph.IsList = true;

                switch (level?.NumberingFormat?.Val?.Value.ToString())
                {
                    case Constants.ListType.Bullet:
                        paragraph.List.ListType = ListType.Marked;
                        break;
                    default:
                        paragraph.List.ListType = ListType.Numbered;
                        break;
                }

                switch (paragraph.List.ListType)
                {
                    case ListType.Marked:
                        text.AppendLine("<ul>");
                        break;
                    case ListType.Numbered:
                        text.AppendLine("<ol>");
                        break;
                }

                _htmlGenerator.GenerateList(paragraph, text);
            }
            else //текущий список
            {
                _htmlGenerator.GenerateList(paragraph, text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (paragraph.IsList)
            {
                switch (paragraph.List?.ListType)
                {
                    case ListType.Marked:
                        text.AppendLine("</ul>");
                        break;
                    case ListType.Numbered:
                        text.AppendLine("</ol>");
                        break;
                }

                paragraph.IsList = false;
            }

            _htmlGenerator.GenerateParagraph(element.InnerText, text);
        }
    }
```

Генерация html кода для списков

```
        public void GenerateList(Elements.Paragraph paragraph, StringBuilder text)
    {
        int? level = paragraph.Element.GetFirstChild<ParagraphProperties>()?
            .GetFirstChild<NumberingProperties>()?.GetFirstChild<NumberingLevelReference>()?.Val?.Value;

        if (level != null)
        {
            var list = paragraph.List;

            if (level > list?.Level)
            {
                switch (paragraph.List?.ListType)
                {
                    case ListType.Marked:
                        text.AppendLine("<ul>");
                        break;
                    case ListType.Numbered:
                        text.AppendLine("<ol>");
                        break;
                }

                list.Level = level.Value;
            }

            if (level < list?.Level)
            {
                switch (paragraph.List?.ListType)
                {
                    case ListType.Marked:
                        text.AppendLine("</ul>");
                        break;
                    case ListType.Numbered:
                        text.AppendLine("</ol>");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        text.AppendLine($"<li>{paragraph.Element.InnerText}</li>");
    }
```

И вот ещё запилил такой костыль если список один в документе, чтобы закрыть тег `<ul>`

```
        public void Handle(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, StringBuilder text)
    {
        var body = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        if(body == null)
            return;

        var paragraph = new Elements.Paragraph
        {
            DocumentPart = mainDocumentPart,
            IsList = false
        };

        foreach (OpenXmlElement element in body.ChildElements)
        {
            string type = element.GetType().ToString();


            paragraph.Element = element;


            switch (type)
            {
                case ElementType.Paragraph:
                    _elementHandler.ParagraphHandle(paragraph, text);
                    continue;
                case ElementType.Table:
                    _elementHandler.TableHandle((Table)element, text);
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (paragraph.IsList)
        {
            switch (paragraph.List?.ListType)
            {
                case Elements.Enums.ListType.Marked:
                    text.AppendLine("</ul>");
                    break;
                case Elements.Enums.ListType.Numbered:
                    text.AppendLine("</ol>");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: какие именно теги и куда именно? данный HTML не является валидным. Вы сами сформировали этот текст или что именно произошло? Откуда у вас потребность его редактировать?

Comment: `то добавить все недостающие html теги` куда именно? здесь полно мест, куда их можно добавить, хоть в конец.

Comment: У меня представлен трёхуровневый список, и мой конвектер только открывает теги ul/ol и может поставить только один закрывающий тег /ul/ol

Comment: Стало еще меньше понятно, если это трехуровневый вложенный список, то он как минимум по спецификации W3C неверно составлен, даже открывающие теги не там стоят.

Comment: А как должен быть составлен трёхуровневый список?)

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь сгенерить HTML, то покажите как и из чего вы его генерите. Здесь надо генерацию исправлять, а не последствия ее косяков костылями затыкать. Верно?

Comment: @aepot, да верно, тогда я сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: Почему бы не просто сохранить документ в формате HTML и его потом подчистить? Скажу по секрету, у меня уже есть готовое решение. :)

Comment: @aepot, подчистить имеете ввиду вручную? А можете поделиться, был бы очень благодарен)

Comment: Нет, програмно, конечно же. Вообще есть хоть прямо сейчас боевой метод, который через буфер обмена с вордом работает. То есть делаешь Ctrl+C в ворде, и можно вставлять в визуальный редактор на сайте готовый чистенький HTML.

Comment: Хотя, давайте я просто покажу вам как генерить HTML с помощью объектов, а не конкатенаций строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто покажу, как создавать вложенные списки в HTML с помощью **HtmlAgilityPack**. Я сам начинал со `StringBuilder` для генерации HTML, и это были очень суровые времена. Используйте для этого специально предназначенные инструменты, и проблема с синтаксисом HTML решится сама собой.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    var ul = doc.CreateElement("ul");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var li = doc.CreateElement("li");
        li.InnerHtml = "Первый";
        ul.AppendChild(li);
    }   
    var ul2 = doc.CreateElement("ul");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var li = doc.CreateElement("li");
        li.InnerHtml = "Второй";
        ul2.AppendChild(li);
    }
    ul.LastChild.AppendChild(ul2);
    var ul3 = doc.CreateElement("ul");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var li = doc.CreateElement("li");
        li.InnerHtml = "Третий";
        ul3.AppendChild(li);
    }
    ul2.LastChild.AppendChild(ul3);
    doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(ul);
    doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("br"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var p = doc.CreateElement("p");
        p.InnerHtml = "Текст";
        doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(p);
    }
    doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("br"));
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
<ul><li>Первый</li><li>Первый<ul><li>Второй</li><li>Второй</li><li>Второй<ul><li>Третий</li><li>Третий</li><li>Третий</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul><br><p>Текст</p><p>Текст</p><p>Текст</p><br>
```

Выходной HTML не отформатирован красиво, но если это минус, то вы можете выполнить постобработку с помощью другой библиотеки, например [HtmlTidy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610903/12888024), наверняка есть и другие.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Первый</li>
  <li>Первый
    <ul>
      <li>Второй</li>
      <li>Второй</li>
      <li>Второй
        <ul>
          <li>Третий</li>
          <li>Третий</li>
          <li>Третий</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<p>Текст</p>
<p>Текст</p>
<p>Текст</p>
<br>
```

То есть по [W3C стандартам](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) дочерний список должен быть внутри `li` старшего списка, а не просто быть вложенным, как у вас. При чем, не внутри пустого `li`, а следовать за контентом этого элемента. Логически подпункты списка обычно относятся к старшему пункту, собственно эта особенность и включена в стандарт.

Comment: не могли бы рассказать подробнее про этот способ 

То есть делаешь Ctrl+C в ворде, и можно вставлять в визуальный редактор на сайте готовый чистенький HTML.