# Не работает тег <a> когда я создаю его из кода .NetCore

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть простая задача - достать из строки ссылку и сделать её активной внутри текста.

Сделано это следующим образом

```
   string wholeMessage = "Ну просто какой то длиииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииииинный текст в конце ссылка например https://google.com"
   string url = "https://google.com"

   wholeMessage = wholeMessage.Replace(url, GetALinkFromAdress(url));

   public static string GetALinkFromAdress(string address)
        {
           
            string before = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"";
            string medium = "\">";
            string after = "</a>";
            return before + address + medium + address + after;
        }
```

Но в итоге в конечной вьюшке ссылка не подсвечивается и не работает, тэг воспринимается как часть строки.

[image: Вот так это выглядит в коде вьюшки]

[image: Как это выглядит в консоли браузера]

Т.е. видно что тэг не обрабатывается браузером. Почему такое может быть и как сделать чтобы обрабатывался?

Comment: Получается, тег просто экранируется и добавляется как текст. А куда вы далее wholeMessage помещаете?

Comment: 1) HTMLString вместо string надо 2) генерить HTML строковыми конкатенациями - странно, ведь есть специальнве инструменты https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1394829/373567

Comment: Покажите, где у вас описано свойство `MessageText` и где вы его присваиваете, и вставьте Blazor разметку как текст, а не как картинку. Тогда можно будет дать нормальный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выше в комментарии указал @aepot, надо конвертировать string в HTMLString
Тогда все заработает

```
HtmlString str = new HtmlString(comment.MessageText);
<div class="message" style="padding:5px;">
  <b>[Message]</b><span>@str</span>
</div>
```

Результат - все работает корректно, ссылки подсвечиваются и кликаются